# How to change shortcut links priority in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, shortcuts, links

How can I change shortcut links priority in left side of Windows File Explorer (like Favorite, Library, Computer)?

[image]

For example, by default Favorite link is top of all other links. So how can I change the priority of Favorite link two second one?